# unit testing opencv android applications

Tags: android, opencv

I am writing an android app in which I use opencv for android for image processing. 
How should I write unit tests for my functions that use opencv? basically my functions get some image from camera( input is an images) and do some processing on it(output is also an image). I want to have unit tests that read some sample images and check the results.
First of all, do I need to write a unit test or android instrumentation test?
Second, where should I put my test image files so they can be accessed by the tests?

Answer (score 0):

I'm developing some OCR library wrapper with extended functionality, target are Android+iOS+WinPhone libs, reusing most of the core source, with only API wrapper being platform specific.

So I develop in C++ under linux, and that's how I run the tests as well. I use [UnitTest++](https://github.com/unittest-cpp) together with [U++ framework](http://ultimatepp.org) (only for tests, the portable library is written in pure C++).

For source version control I use git, and that's where I store my testing images as well.

And that's probably the worst thing about my setup, while git generally is very nice and performing well, most of the nifty extensions are some web applications written in script languages, and they don't like binary commits with several MiB of difference. Also cloning the repository for every new developer is a bit cumbersome, currently the repo is 4+GiB.

So if I would do this one more time from scratch, I would put into git only very basic images verifying the basic functionality. Other images used for QA testing and training I would put into some binary .zip files and upload it to some cloud archive with history and backup. As they don't get updated very often, but when they do, it affects the rest of git usage a bit.

I would definitely aim to write functions which are low level enough to use only data and opencv, so you don't need android API for anything. And to run them as either JUnit tests, or C++ tests. Use Android instrumentation only for tests where Android API is inevitable, as it is very slow and you have to have some device connected (or emulator, or robolectric, either way you are on 10-100x slower development mode when compared to instant C++ compilation).

With the development of Android Studio and gradle (I mean performance) I'm actually trying to avoid Android development as much as possible, so I'm very glad I made native C++ lib and I need Android stuff only for final testing on device.

So ... that's my experience, YMMV, take with grain of salt.

---

edit: to give some more specific answers
for android instrumented unit tests you can put images into assets of /testAndroid/ directory I think? Or create custom build-installation step, which will copy files trough adb to the target device to some public directory from local project files.

With JUnit tests you can set working directory in the configuration of runner, so I usually keep things somewhere inside of /test/ directory, so I have them under git control as well.

It's the same with any other environment (C++/linux), there's always a way to set up pretty much anything, if you find the correct configuration switch or file, so you can organize the project as you like.

The current template for android projects in Android Studio (with src/ branching into test/main/..., /build/* being outside of everything) is quite fine, I'm using similar setup also for my C++ projects, didn't notice any serious drawback, usually it naturally fits all my needs.